# Meta Stack Exchange should not be listed as a "Technology" site

Tags: discussion, bug, meta, stackexchange.com, footer

Meta.Se does not qualify as a "Technology" site and should go in another category: the obvious correct answer of "Weird and Wonderful", or missing that any of "Culture/Recreation", "Business" or "Professional" is closer to where I'd expect to find this site.

Look where I found it [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-name)

[image: Stack Exchange sites list, open to the "Technology" section; Meta Stack Exchange is listed]

But it's correctly placed in a special category in the footer.

[image: "Other" category opened in the footer; Meta is there]

Can we move it to a sensible category and/or at least make its categorization consistent across the footer and stackexchange.com?

Comment: Isn't the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites a *technology*?

Comment: @CodyGray no, it's a community, we discuss rules, how-to, etc. as well as the tool part. And in any case, it should be techology in both places. Please don't download unless you are OK with that.

Comment: Where else to put it? This site is for questions about the *software* that powers the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog is it, really?

Comment: My bet is it got that category from before the split and nobody cared or noticed until now. IIRC "uncategorized" is also an available option in the sites category list. That could be a temporary solution that doesn't need 6 to 8 to have a new tab introduced.

Comment: Not that you're wrong, but the divisions are rather arbitrary anyways: why are Amateur Radio and Mechanics under "Culture/Recreation" rather than Tech? Why is Arts and Crafts under "Life/Arts" but Woodworking under "Culture/Recreation"? Academia, Law, and Medical Sciences are under "Life/Arts", not "Professional". "Science" has Philosophy but not History or Politics... /shrugs

Comment: @JoshCaswell I know, but at least, let's pick one and stick to it! At the moment it's in different categories in the footer and the stackexchange.com site...

Comment: I would expect MSE to be in the same category as [Community Building.SE](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: I know MSE is technically a "main" site, at least in functionality, but its purpose is as a meta site that applies to the entire network. Why should it even be listed with the main Q&A sites?

Comment: On another note, having MSE show up under the same category as a bunch of sites where you ask questions about technology may be one of the reasons MSE gets so many questions that aren't about SE.

Comment: I'd almost argue that its a site*about* a bit of technology - the platform that SE sites are built on.  The "soft" aspects of a technology is still a technology. That said, with the de-emphasis as a place to track bugs... I also see your points. I'm solidly neutral on this

Comment: If only we had a system of tags.